# recursive run() in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion

I have had an idea when I wrote a thread. I was thinking about something like:

```
class myThread extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        if(condition){
            //doSomething
        } else {
            sleep(10000);
            run();
        }
    }
}
```

Can I do this? I am sure this is not a good coding style, but is there anything else that speaks against this?

Comment: Ever heard of _stackoverflow_?

Comment: @nosid If the value of `condition` changes then there's nothing "wrong" with this method. I think OP is asking if you can call a `Thread`'s `run` method multiple times.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure your JVM will speak against this. It's called StackOverflowError.

Comment: I know about stackoverflowErrors. And of course, these can happen in recursions. but they can happen in any recursion. I know that this is not the best style. omfg, i forgot one important thing....

Comment: I edited my question, forgot the sleep. I am waiting for something else in this time that makes condition come true

Comment: So you're implementing a polling thread? Look into [`ScheduledExectuorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: Also, I'm surprised that so many people are screaming "stack overflow!" when that's obviously not what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, nothing speaks against recursively calling `run()` from within itself. Nevertheless, I'd suggest to move the code into a `Runnable` that's then run by the thread as it is bad design to subclass `Thread` and override `run` to implement a task:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // ...
        run(); // recursive call
        // ...
    }
}

// somewhere else:
Thread thread = new Thread(new MyTask());
thread.start();

// or even better:
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(new MyTask());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are risking a `StackOverflowError` doing this, because the stack will only grow until the condition is no longer met.  It is simpler to do this non-recursively.

```
public void run() {
    while(condition) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. I forgot about the sleep(). I know that there is a risk of a stack overflow, but this can be the case in almost any recursive implementation

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an infinite loop and a `volatile` boolean flag. You can update `flag` from outside the thread as well to come out of the thread (stop the thread) at any time.

```
class myThread extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean flag;

    public void run(){
        while(flag){
            if(condition){
               flag = false;
               break;
            }
            //doSomething
        }
    }
}
```